# C# with Visual Studio query date with today value

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio

I'm using Visual Studio query builder to take query `WHERE date = CURDATE()`  (like `YYYY-MM-DD`) from a SQL Server database, but I get errors.

In SQL Server I have this table

```
TABLE [dbo].[dodajpaniex]
(
    [data] [date] NOT NULL,
    [godzina] [text] NULL,
    ....
)
```

What is correct query to retrieve data from the SQL Server column `data` with visual studio query builder = CURDATE()

Sorry for my english :)

Comment: show your `visual studio query builder `

Comment: `WHERE [date] = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)`  .............. `CURDATE` I think is MySQL not SQL Server.

Comment: Is your issue resolve ?

Comment: `ntext`, `text`, and `image` data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use `nvarchar(max)`, `varchar(max)`, and `varbinary(max)` instead. [See details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)